# iTextSharp unable to read Pre-Filled PDF Form File which is digitally signed in C#.Net

Tags: c#, itext, pdfbox, itext7

I have been trying to read Pre-Filled PDF Form File which is digitally signed in C#.Net using iTextSharp 5.5.13.0

I have tried many ways but able to get the Field Names but the values are blank.

I have used all possible ways like ParsePdf, GetFormFieldNames & GetFormFieldNamesWithValues, ReadPDFformDataPageWise, ExtractXML but unable to read the values.

File which I am trying to read : [Pre-Filled PDF Form File](http://www.data-ligence.com/PDFDigitalSigned.pdf)

```
       using iTextSharp.text;
       using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
       using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
       using org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel;
       using org.apache.pdfbox.util;
       using System;
       using System.Collections;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.ComponentModel;
       using System.Data;
       using System.Drawing;
       using System.IO;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Text;
       using System.Threading.Tasks;
       using System.Windows.Forms;
       using System.Xml;

       private static string GetFormFieldNames(PdfReader pdfReader)
    {
        return string.Join("\r\n", pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields
                                       .Select(x => x.Key).ToArray());
    }

    private static string GetFormFieldNamesWithValues(PdfReader pdfReader)
    {
        return string.Join("\r\n", pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields
                                       .Select(x => x.Key + "=" +
                                        pdfReader.AcroFields.GetField(x.Key))
                                       .ToArray());
    }

    public string ParsePdf(string fileName)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("fileName");
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            for (int page = 0; page < reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page + 1, strategy);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                {
                    sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text))));
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
       public bool ExtractXML(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
            AcroFields afields = reader.AcroFields;
            var result = new XmlDocument();
            result.LoadXml(string.Format("<{0}/>", "xml"));
            foreach (string keyname in afields.Fields.Keys)
            {
                AcroFields.Item item = afields.GetFieldItem(keyname);
                XmlElement elt = result.CreateElement(keyname);
                elt.InnerXml = "<![CDATA[" + afields.GetField(keyname) + "]]>\";";
                result.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elt);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Read all 'Form values/keys' from an existing multi-page PDF document
    public void ReadPDFformDataPageWise(string PDFFileName)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PDFFileName);
        AcroFields form = reader.AcroFields;
        try
        {
            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> kvp in form.Fields)
                {
                    switch (form.GetFieldType(kvp.Key))
                    {
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_COMBO:
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_LIST:
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_RADIOBUTTON:
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_NONE:
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_PUSHBUTTON:
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_SIGNATURE:
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_TEXT:
                            int fileType = form.GetFieldType(kvp.Key);
                            string fieldValue = form.GetField(kvp.Key);
                            string translatedFileName = form.GetTranslatedFieldName(kvp.Key);

                            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + fileType + " " + fieldValue + " " + translatedFileName + ".....";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why did you use the pdfbox label?

Comment: Was doing R&D and trying to see all possible ways to read data but it did not work for me..

Comment: Your form is a hybrid XFA/AcroForm form. For such forms iText tries to retrieve values for the AcroForm field names from the XFA definitions. In this case, though, the definitions appear pretty complex, probably too complex for the simple XFA support by iText. Thus, I would propose removing the XFA part before retrieving the values in the AcroForm fields themselves.

Comment: **Thanks mkl**, You are correct. You saved my day. Firstly I did not know the type of PDFs and you rightly said "XFA/AcroForm form" so I did some google and came across this link http://demo.itextsupport.com/xfademo/uploadpdf.jsp in which I uploaded the PDF and the data got extracted in XML format. I am now going to use the same method of Flattening the Dynamic XFA forms.

Comment: This is what I wanted and it is finally working :-

        public void ExtractPdf(String InputPDFFileName, String OutputXMLFileName) 
        {
         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(InputPDFFileName);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
            stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
            AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
            XfaForm xfa = form.Xfa;
            
            form.Xfa.DatasetsNode.InnerXml.ToString();
            form.Xfa.DatasetsNode.OuterXml.ToString();

Comment: Great. Please make that an actual answer (not a mere comment) which you can accept after some time by clicking the tick at its upper left.